# mod_rewrite with browser language and non-www domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following rule to redirect the domain to EN version of the site based on browser language:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en [L,R=302]
```

this works ok with www.domain.com but fails redirecting from now-www to www. 
For example, fails to redirect http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com/en, that's what i'm trying to achieve.

What should i add to the rule? 
Thank you!

Comment: So you want both `http://domain.com` and `http://www.domain.com` to be redirect it to `http://www.domain.com/en` or just to append `/en` in both cases: `http://domain.com/en` and `http://www.domain.com/en`?

Comment: Hi! thank you for your reply! i want the first one you mentioned, i want both to be redirected to http:// www.domain.com/en

Comment: Okay. But, still not quite clear. From your rule-set, the rest of the URL is lost when redirected. For example, something like `http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/etc/` would end up as `http://www.domain.com/en` ¿Are you sure you want to throw away the rest of the URI?

Comment: Well i'm not experienced with .htaccess rules i just copied this rule from a drupal forum and it's working as expected. People who have english as browser language get redirected to `http://www.domain.com/en`and if a use a link  `http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2`it goes to that page.. the rule isn't convering just the redirection from non-www to www, i would like to keep the same redirection.. is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To redirect non-www to www, add this rule-set before the one in your question, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#This is the rule set in the question:
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en [L,R=302]
```

Since you say the actual rule-set is working fine except for the `www` issue, I did not modify it or test it.

What the top rule rule does, is to insert www to all URLs. That's all. It is independent from the rule in your question, but if you want to limit that conversion to EN language only, move this line:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en.*$ [NC]`

in the last rule-set, to the first one, like this:

```
....
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en.*$ [NC]
....
```

**OPTION**

To redirect all requests that don't match the previous language rules, just place the following lines at the bottom, after all language rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en [L,R=302]
```

It will redirect by default all incoming requests to the English section.

So, your .htaccess file should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^sv.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sv [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nb.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nb [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en [L,R=302]
```

I suggest you replace all `R=302` with `R=301`. It's better for SEO purposes.

Comment: Once again, i'm very gratefull, this is working as expected but my site has 2 more languages norwegian and swedish, based in your response i copied the rule for each language and all it's working fine. But how can i redirect all the other languages, if they aren't  english,norwegian or swedish, to the english version of the site?

Comment: Okay. `en` is for English, what's for norwegian and swedish?

Comment: `nb` for norwegian and `sv` for swedish.

Comment: @Jose Updated my answer with an option.

Comment: Hi! Should i replace the other language selections? i pasted after and  before language redirections and it seems not to be working. Maybe i'm doing something wrong..

Comment: No. Should be after the other ones. Try replacing this `!(en|nb|sv).*$` with this `!^(en|nb|sv).*$` and let me know. Needless to say that you must test it in the correct language environment to trigger the redirection for the other languages.

Comment: @Jose I think I understand what is happening. If `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` holds the string `en,sv`, for example, the negative condition will match and the rule is skipped. That configuration is common and can include several languages. So the way I implemented it, is not the best one. Let me figure out another way and I will update the answer.

Comment: Ok! Of course i'm testing the several languages in the browser. Thank you!

Comment: @Jose Updated my answer. I think the best way to achieve what you want is by redirecting by default to `/en` all requests that don't match the previous language rules. No need for more conditions.

Comment: Hi @faa i need to upgrade my rule, i tried to add a condition for when you request a `www.domain.com/subdomain` based on current language rules to rewrite the url to add the language code before subdomain `www.domain.com/nb/subdomain` in case of norwegian language.. i copied the nb rule and added subdomain it worked but i lost the root redirection.. i think i need to add that on the current rule.. can you help one more time? Thank you!

Comment: I would be glad to do it, but I am pretty sure this thread was closed because of the added questions to the original one. So, I suggest you open another thread for this new requirement. Just explain what you have now and the modifications you want. It won't take much time or effort and we'll be complying with SO policies.

Comment: Hi @faa! opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377717/apache-mod-rewrite-accept-language-subdomain-redirection