# Apache mod_rewrite accept language subdomain redirection

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i have a multilingual site with 3 languages and i'm using the following rules to redirect requests to the right version of the website based in browser accept language.

```
#swedish
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^sv.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sv [L,R=301]

#norwegian bokmal
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nb.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nb [L,R=301]

#norwegian
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^no.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nb [L,R=301]

#all others go to english
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en [L,R=301]
```

I need to upgrade this rules to do the same redirections keeping subdomains too

```
Example for a norwegian request:
www.domain.com/subdomain -> www.domain.com/nb/subdomain
```

How can i achieve this?

I have thank @faa for helping me out with the current rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

#### Question Description

Regarding the *pages vs subdomains* issue in your comments, in this specific case is irrelevant. The fact is the incoming URL in your question is**:** `www.domain.com/subdomain` and, except for the name, `/subdomain` is clearly a page.

A real **subdomain** is indeed a domain that is part of another domain and the URL format that holds it, is something like `subdomain.domain.com`, so there was no confusion on my part.

What it is not clear enough, is how the redirection will be handled. According to your question, but replacing "subdomain" with the whole path, here are some examples:

1. `www.domain.com/` should go to  `www.domain.com/LangCode/`, (previous working redirection)
2. `www.domain.com/page` should go to  `www.domain.com/LangCode/page`
3. `www.domain.com/page1/page2/page3/etc/` should go to  `www.domain.com/LangCode/page1/page2/page3/etc`. This possibility is not in the question, but eventually could be neded.

In those cases, the pages in the incoming and redirected URLs should have the same name, but, although in the incoming URL do not have to exist, in the redirected URL the pages MUST exist and so a loading default script (index.php or index.html, for example) to handle the request.

Which means, there has to be a script in each page subject to redirection. I would say at least 2 for each language.

As far a I understand, that's what the question and complementary comments indicate, but it seems it is not a practical approach.

#### Suggested Solution

A better approach could be a single script at the root folder that handles all requests. This is an idea that can be better described with examples:

1. `www.domain.com/` always showing in the browser's address bar but going internally to
   `www.domain.com/lang_handler.php?lang=sv` or
2. `www.domain.com/page1/` always showing in the browser's address bar but going internally to `www.domain.com/lang_handler.php?lang=sv&target_page1=page1`

This can be achieved in .htaccess with mod_rewrite directives. Here is an example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase  /

# Set managed languages here, except default (en)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(sv|ne|no).*$ [NC]

# Replace the names of the script and the parameters in the next 2 lines
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !lang_handler\.php              [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?/?$  lang_handler.php?lang=%1&target_page1=$1  [L,QSA]

# If no match, set English
# Replace the names of the script and the parameters in the next 2 lines
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !lang_handler\.php             [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?/?$  lang_handler.php?lang=en&target_page1=$1  [L,QSA]
```

The above rule set maps silently

`http://www.domain.com/` or `http://www.domain.com/page1`

To

`http://www.domain.com/lang_handler.php?lang=LangCode&target_page1=page1`

Where `LangCode` is `sv` `ne` `no` or `en` by default.

This example only works for 1 page or no page. Any number of pages can be handled though, but the rules have to be modified accordingly. More parameters and regex groups have to be added to the RewriteRules.

Comment: Hi! Applying that rules it gives me a redirect loop error it adds the language code over and over like `www.domain.com/en/en/en/en/en/en` removing `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.` does the same.

Comment: @Jose Updated my answer. Please try again and let me know.

Comment: Hi again! With that rules putting just `www.domain.com` it remains in `www.domain.com` there's no language redirection. if i add a subdomain to the domain it does a redirect loop like `www.domain.com/en/en/en/en/en/en/subdomain`

Comment: @Jose Updated my answer. This time the rules are tested and work fine under the conditions described in my answer.

Comment: Sorry. I thought that was the idea. But it seems you want the previous behavior also. I will modify my answer and let you know.

Comment: Hi @faa, i tried in `EN`, going to `www.domain.com` it doesn't redirect to `www.domain.com\en` going `www.domain.com/subdomain` it's ok! In the other languages goes to (ex. `NB`) `www.domain.com/nb/index.php` which i don't have. I don't know if i can do such thing in drupal. Was it easier to get what i want without adding scripts if i just want to do that in a fixed subdomain? Ex: in a request for fixedsubdomain i just add the language code to url before fixedsubdomain `www.domain.com/fixedsubdomain -> www.domain.com/nb/fixedsubdomain` fixedsubdomain exists in all languages. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. It is always better to do that kind of routing in a script when possible. It is feasible in .htaccess in this case, though, but let me know what you decide. I will be glad to make the necessary adjustments to make it work.

Comment: By the way, the reason for this: `www.domain.com/nb/index.php` is you must have a script in each subdomain to process the redirected request. I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, i guided you wrong from the beggining... this is not a subdomain it's a page! but because i'm using a module (clean urls) to have a better SEO for the site i forgot it.. so the redirections should be for a page (`www.domain.com/page -> www.domain.com/nb/page`) the name of the page is the same for all languages. This is easier to do? Should i mark your answer right and post a new topic? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Jose That's not necessary. It is basically the same question and there is no accepted answer yet, so don't think there will be a problem. I will update my answer with some comments about the page issue.

Comment: Ok! If it's easier i just need that rule to work with one page.

Comment: Hi! Ok, i have a lang_handler.php script. When i do a `www.domain.com` it sends to the right lang version in url but it gives too many redirects error. Using a page or subdomain goes to `www.domain.com/en/index.php` and gives the same error.. I have other rules in .htaccess generated by drupal maybe there's some conflits?... Can i send you the .htaccess file?

Comment: I rather think it is problem with the way redirection is done in the script and eventually conflicts with existing scripts that should be updated or removed. Try to test only one language for now and replace the [L] with [R] temporarily, so you can see what's going on. Nobody said it was easy though, although it is easier than the other option, but I am sure it is a definitive and global solution that will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: Hi @faa! Sorry, i could not reply earlier. I think i made it work now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

$1 should do the trick.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^no.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^q\=) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nb/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It's not working as expected, there's no changes in redirection.

Comment: Edit RewriteRule and try : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/nb/%{QUERY_STRING}

Comment: Just editing the RewriteRule it sends the site to page not found /.