# How can I change a specific directory without changing the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to create a directory switcher on my website (WordPress) like this:

- `example.com/currentpage/` to `example.com/fr/currentpage/`
- `example.com` to `example.com/fr/`

I tried this JavaScript code but it didn't work.

```
<script>
  //Get current Pagename
  var currentPage = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

  //Change href for link
  document.querySelector('a[href="/fr/"]').setAttribute('href', '/fr/'+ currentPage);
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to redirect based on language.

For this, is easier to be done by *Apache* (if that is the server you are using), using the *mod_rewrite* module.

Please take a look at this other question on SO: 
[Apache mod_rewrite accept language subdomain redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377717/apache-mod-rewrite-accept-language-subdomain-redirection)

Comment: yes , but i need javascript code , because i created language switcher with css and html own my website

Comment: Since you are using Wordpress, have you tried [https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_locale/](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_locale/)?

Comment: i using 5 wordpress on my webiste , and also i have no skill to php code's ..